# Create Custom helpers Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a custom asp.net mvc3 helper .

To use that helper, I should write syntax like below

```
@Html.DisplayMyCustomHelper(model => model.FullName)
```

Expected Output

```
Full Name (Value Picked from model's Display attribute)= Current Value Of Property
```

Eg:

```
public Class User
{
      [Display(Name="Full Name")]
      public string FullName{get;set;}
}

User = new User{FullName="Tom Cruise"};
```

**Inside Razor**

```
@model User
@Html.DisplayMyCustomHelper(model => model.FullName)
```

**Expected OutPut**

Full Name= Tom Cruise

---

How can i do this?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs this is good tutorial to create custom helpers in mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayMyCustomHelper<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        const string format = "{0} = {1}";

        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var model = metadata.Model;

        var result = string.Format(format, metadata.DisplayName, model == null ? string.Empty : model.ToString());

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
    }
```

Comment: it worked, i will accept it in few hours, just make one change in your answer , inside string.format replace "metadata.DisplayName" with "metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName"

Comment: @Praveen man, every piece of code written on stack overflow as answers is not the one to directly copy and paste in your production environment. The general idea is shown in my answer, and you are free do change what ever you want in it : )

Comment: he he, u are right. Could you suggest me how to do this | helper inside view = "@Html.MyDisplayFor(m => m)" , how to loop thru each property of model inside method "MyDisplayFor"

Comment: Take a look at http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html, section Tabular Layout, in Object template brad explains what you want